# Postman: Wanted to validate data values getting from API in JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I wanted to check some combinations of validations for values I am getting from API request in [postman](/questions/tagged/postman)like 
if `"tracked": "Yes"` then `analytics > "transitTime": 239` should be present.

The snippet of API response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [{
    "id": 107267,
    "branchId": "22",
    "status": "1",
    "googleETA": "2018-02-01 20:44:51",
    "runDate": "2018-01-29",
    "runOfTheDay": "1",
    "ATD": "2018-01-29 14:02",
    "simCarrier": "Vodafone",
    "pingStatus": "Ok",
    "driverName": "test",
    "shipperCompanyId": "007",
    "ETA": "2018-01-30 12:31:00",
    "locationSource": "sim",
    "created_at": "2018-01-29 07:05:54",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-29 12:35:40",
    "tracked": "Yes",
    "analytics": {
      "loadingTime": 55.62,
      "unloadingTime": 0,
      "transitTime": 239
    },
    "trackingStatusAtClosure": {
      "Origin": "No",
      "Transit": "No",
      "Destination": "No"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? The postman docs are a good starting point

Comment: What does it look like if `tracked` equals No?

Comment: If tracked is NO then all analytics values will be null

Comment: Does the solution I provided give you enough information to try and create these checks for yourself?

Comment: @DannyDainton it did,I got the idea how to validate them , thanks :)

Comment: Cool. Would you like to accept that as an answer and close out the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic check and I would advise against using it anywhere other than practising in a local environment.

```
pm.test("Basic Check", () => {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json().data
    for(i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        if(jsonData[i].tracked === 'Yes') {
            pm.expect(jsonData[i].analytics.transitTime).to.not.be.null
        } else {
            console.log('Tracked does not equal Yes')
        }
    }
})
```

As your data only has one item in the `data` array you don't really *need* to add the `for` loop but I added it in for you so you can see that the same check would run if you have more than one item. If the `tracked` property is 'Yes' then the test is checking if `analytics.transitTime` not null. Like I said, its a basic check and it's not doing a great deal but hopefully that will give you the information you need to get started.